# How does WindowSoftInputMode work?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

My layout requires itself to adapt to the available space when the keyboard appears, so I have this set in my Manifest:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize"
```

How does `WindowSoftInputMode` work, though? How does it choose what to adjust (padding, margins, image size, etc.)?

Is it possible to not resize a specific view (like an `ImageView`) and instead take away more padding? Can I choose what it resizes (besides just `adjustResize` and `adjustPan`)?

Answer (score 0):

Completely impractical to handle resizing UI elements yourself and I understand it is discouraged. You can use the below code to explicitly handle soft input:

```
public void showSoftKeyboard(View view) {
    if (view.requestFocus()) {
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)
            getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.showSoftInput(view, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
    }
}
```

Check out [THIS](http://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/visibility.html) on how to handle the keyboard...